# Вызов переменной с динамическим именем Lazarus Pascal

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

есть форма со списками Memo1, Memo2, Memo3 и т.д
Нужно в цикле задать текст внутри списка по виду

```
i := 1;
while i < 5 do
 begin
 Memoi.Caption := i;
 i := i + 1;
 end;
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как указать Memoi то бишь динамически изменить имя переменной для её записи, прошу подсказать, как это сделать.

Comment: используй массивы, тут вам не пхп)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как более простой вариант - заведите и заполните массив и используйте его:

```
fMemos: array [0..2] of TMemo;

...

fMemos[0] := Memo1;
fMemos[1] := Memo2;
fMemos[2] := Memo3;

...

for i := 0 to High(fMemos) do
begin
  fMemos[i].Caption := IntToStr(i);
end;
```

---

Как более универсальный вариант - используйте теги (`Tag`). В конструкторе форм, у каждого элемента пропишите тег, а в программе идите по контейнеру с элементами и проверяйте по тегам:

```
for i := 0 to Panel1.ChildCount - 1 do
if (Panel1.Childs[i] is TMemo) and (Panel1.Childs[i].Tag > 0) then
begin
  TMemo(Panel1.Childs[i]).Caption := IntToStr(Panel1.Childs[i].Tag);
end;
```